# complex Find and replace using regular expression

Tags: regex, pattern-matching

I have created a new function which is to be replaced multiple times

original func call:
`fun_x(fun_y("param1","param2","param3"),...);`

new func call:

`fun("param3",...);`

So I want to remove param1 and param2 and make param3 as first param and whatever arglist pass it as second onward param.

Any idea will be helpful as I have to replace it like 1000 times.

Comment: Has to be done programmatically or via IDE ?

Comment: Can `param1/param2` contain `,` or `"` ?

Comment: `perl` possible? :D

Comment: Any method will be helpful I am using npp and Visual Studio. Even a python script is ok

Comment: Use this regex "_y|("\w+",){2}" to match and replace it with empty string and you should get the form you want. Check here https://regex101.com/r/Qgpthc/1

Comment: `param1/param2` can contain a `,`

Comment: Give real examples if you want real solutions.

Comment: You could consider one round of replacements restricted to all the simple cases, and do the rest by hand. Usually there is a tradeoff between a bit of repetitive grunt work, versus trying to find the magic solution (which sometimes amounts to writing a small parser).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `"` cannot be inside the first 2 strings parameters:

Match

```
fun_x\(fun_y\("[^"]*", *"[^"]*", *("[^"]+")\)
```

and replace by

```
fun($1
```

https://regex101.com/r/hqsw1m/1

Comment: You are the real MVP

Answer (score 0):

Work your way around the problem: use a preprocessor macro:

```
#define fun_y(a1, a2, a3) (a3)
```

Perhaps the IDE would then have an option to *expand a macro in place*?

Comment: Out of curiosity, which IDEs have such an option?

Comment: @Evg: not IDE, but C/C++ macro.(which is target language of OP).

Comment: Expanding a single macro sounds like such a niche feature, it's more likely that an IDE would ship with some other code refactoring tool instead. Likewise, I'm very curious if what you propose exists anywhere.

Comment: @Jarod42, I though "Expand in place" command was meant: you right-click a macro in IDE, choose this command and get the macro replaced by its definition.